# Removing an item in a linked list error with an instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, linked-list

I am making a linkedlist, and I had to add in some different functions such as max, min , count and index for my list. I now have to add a remove function which is this snippet of code.

```
def removeItem(self, position):

        ''' removeItem removes a selected, because python has a built in "garbage remover",
        you don't have to physically delete the node, you only have to skip that node link and python will destroy it
        by it self.'''

        currentNode = ListNode
        previousNode = None
        count = 0

        while count != position:
            #This is a quick check to make sure the next node isn't empty.
            if currentNode.link is None:
                print("Position Invalid")
                return None
            previousNode = currentNode
            currentNode = currentNode.link
            count += 1

        #Node.Link should link to the next node in the sequence.
        previousNode.link = currentNode.link
        return currentNode
```

I am basically just trying to link over the next node in the sequence, so that the built-in garbage remover will remove that node from the sequence. However, I am getting the following error message, which I know has to do something with my instance.

```
C:\Python33\python.exe "C:/Users/koopt_000/Desktop/College/Sophomore Semester 2/Computer Science 231/Chapter4/Test.py"
900
Traceback (most recent call last):
1
  File "C:/Users/koopt_000/Desktop/College/Sophomore Semester 2/Computer Science 231/Chapter4/Test.py", line 17, in <module>
1
    print(linked_list.removeItem(3))
2
  File "C:\Users\koopt_000\Desktop\College\Sophomore Semester 2\Computer Science 231\Chapter4\LinkedList.py", line 199, in removeItem
    if currentNode.link is None:
AttributeError: type object 'ListNode' has no attribute 'link'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my testing code:

```
from ListNode import ListNode
from LinkedList import LinkedList

node1 = ListNode(1)
node2 = ListNode(900)
node3 = ListNode(3)
node4 = ListNode(99)
node1.link = node2
node2.link = node3
node3.link = node4

linked_list = LinkedList((1, 900, 3, 99))
print(linked_list.__max__())
print(linked_list.__min__())
print(linked_list.getCount(900))
print(linked_list.getIndex(3))
print(linked_list.removeItem(3))
```

This is my code for my ListNode class:

```
# ListNode.py
class ListNode(object):

    def __init__(self, item = None, link = None):

        '''creates a ListNode with the specified data value and link
        post: creates a ListNode with the specified data value and link'''

        self.item = item
        self.link = link
```

This is my code for my LinkedList class:

```
from ListNode import ListNode

class LinkedList(object):

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self, seq=()):

        """ Pre: Creates a Linked List
        Post: Creates a list containing the items in the seq=()"""

        if seq == ():

            # If there is no items to be put into the list, then it creates an empty one.
            self.head = None

        else:

            # Creates a node for the first item.
            self.head = ListNode(seq[0], None)

            # If there are remaining items, then they're added while keeping track of the last node.
            last = self.head
            for item in seq[1:]:
                last.link = ListNode(item, None)
                last = last.link

        self.size = len(seq)

    #-------------------------------------------------------------

    def __len__(self):

        '''Pre: Nothing.
           Post: Returns the number of items in the list.'''

        return self.size

    #-------------------------------------------------------------
    def __max__(self):

        ''' Goes through each node and compares what the max is for the linked list.
        Post: Finds the max of the linked list and returns that value.'''

        if self.head is None:
        return None
        max_value = self.head.item
        node = self.head.link

        while node is not None:
            if node.item > max_value:
                max_value = node.item
            node = node.link
        return max_value

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def __min__(self):

        ''' Goes through each node and compares what the min is for the linked list.
        Post: Finds the min of the linked list and returns that value.'''

        if self.head is None:
            return None
        min_value = self.head.item
        node = self.head.link

        while node is not None:
            if node.item < min_value:
                min_value = node.item
            node = node.link
        return min_value

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def getCount(self, yourData):

        ''' This function counts the amount of times a certain item is in the Linked List.'''

        count = 0
        node = self.head

        for i in range(self.size):
            data = node.item
            if data is yourData:
                count += 1
            node = node.link
        return count

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def getIndex(self, yourData):

        ''' getIndex finds the index of the selected item and returns that value. '''

        node = self.head

        if node is None:
            return None

        for i in range(self.size):
            data = node.item
            if data == yourData:
                return i
            node = node.link

        raise IndexError


    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def removeItem(self, position):

        ''' removeItem removes a selected, because python has a built in "garbage remover",
        you don't have to physically delete the node, you only have to skip that node link and python will destroy it
        by it self.'''

        currentNode = ListNode
        previousNode = None
        count = 0

        while count != position:
            #This is a quick check to make sure the next node isn't empty.
            if currentNode.link == None:
                print("Position Invalid")
                return None
            previousNode = currentNode
            currentNode = currentNode.link
            count += 1

        #Node.Link should link to the next node in the sequence.
        previousNode.link = currentNode.link
        return currentNode

    #--------------------------------------------------------------
```

If anyone could help me out to find out why my removeItem function isn't working that would be helpful!

On a side note, I'm also trying to make a doubly linked list of this list, I know I need to add a prev_node function into my ListNode function, but what else do I need to add? Thanks again!

Comment: Shouldn't `currentNode` be set to `list.head` instead of the `ListNode` type?

Comment: When I do that it comes with an error saying type object 'list' has no attribute 'head'.

Comment: I'm sorry, `self.head`

Comment: Hm, now when I do self.head it works but prints out this weird statement. "<ListNode.ListNode object at 0x00000000000026E9320>"  Any reason I got that?